# Rebuilding Indexes with SOLR throws Exceptions

Tags: sxa, content-search, solr

I set up a fresh Sitecore 9.1 with SXA on my local machine.
When rebuilding the indexes, I get the following messages:

1. (Core)

> 19676 14:50:03 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField:
>   __solr_norm_field_name for indexable: sitecore://core/{4255D463-DBA7-4E62-8B5D-68986A39BD96}?lang=da&ver=1
>   Exception: System.Exception Message: Item "/sitecore/client/Business
>   Component Library/version
>   2/Layouts/Renderings/Common/ActionControl/Action/__Standard Values" is
>   not a template section. (method:
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateFieldItem.op_Implicit(Item item)). Source:
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateFieldItem.op_Implicit(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateSectionItem.op_Implicit(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateFieldItem.op_Implicit(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.FieldNames.TypeResolving.Index.ComputedFields.TemplateFieldComputedIndexField.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable
>   indexable)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__0(IComputedIndexField
>   computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)

2. (Master)

> 14364 15:05:22 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawler :
>   AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {668126E9-5A1E-4553-974B-A26400B5BAD7}
>   Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException Message:
>
> 400   215     
>       org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
>       org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
>      ERROR:
>   [doc=sitecore://master/{507ae52a-d1cf-4a62-8198-0229504cf250}?lang=pl-pl&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index]
>   unknown field 'extension_t_pl'   400
>
> Source: SolrNet
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1  parameters)
>
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
>
>   at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
>
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1
>   group, Int32 groupSize)
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddDocument(Object
>   itemToAdd, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexOperations.ApplyPermissionsThenIndex(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexable version)
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.WebException Message: The remote server returned
>   an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   Source: System
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String
>   contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

3. (SXA Master)

> 3244 15:24:15 WARN  [Index=sitecore_sxa_master_index] Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {12D57DC3-35B4-40A0-B041-80D90B9983BB}
>   ...
>   copyField dest :'extension_t_pl_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.
>   ...
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: copyField dest :'extension_t_pl_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.
>   at rg.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.registerCopyField(IndexSchema.java:902)
>   at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.addCopyFields(ManagedIndexSchema.java:784)
>   at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.addCopyFields(ManagedIndexSchema.java:81)
>   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:450)

All other indexs ran withoout errors/warnings.
Has anyone any idea what could be missing?
The schemas are populated.

---

**Update:**
If you have the same problems with the master index and the SXA master index, please refer to the answer of @Dawid Rutkowski
The issue with the core index is still current.

Comment: I currently have a ticket open with Sitecore for a very similar issue. Will let you know the outcome.

Comment: I'm looking forward to hearing from you. I found a blog post where the author has the same problem, but has no solution yet, too.

Answer (score 4):

The errors you see on the `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_core_index` are not SXA related. SXA is not overriding Sitecore indexes any more, it is using its own indexes.

The last error related to a missing field:

> 'extension_t_pl_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a
>   dynamicField

is caused by wrong Solr server configuration. You Solr schema is missing a dynamic field. Please edit managed-schema file manually and add a following dynamic field:

```
<dynamicField name="*_t_pl" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

This should solve your problems. Keep in mind that populating managed schema from Sitecore might not create dynamic fields for all of the languages you are using in your content. You might need to add some fields manually to the sechema file.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem with the SXA master index. I see that the items have a polish item version, but the instance has no polish language. The items that cause the issue in the general master index come with the SXA installation, so _imho_ it is an issue of SXA. In the installation guide for SXA it says that you have to populate the SOLR Managed Schema, but it does not add your node while having items with a polish language version. I cannot remember polish being a _standard_ language of Sitecore. Maybe some developer accidentally did not remove these versions.

Comment: After clicking Populate Solr Managed Schema again and your node still being in the managed-schema, the error comes up again.

Comment: Of course, it will pop up again because populating schema will override managed-schema file (all manual changes are gone). This issue has already been fixed a few weeks ago (polish versions removed). Just wait for SXA 1.8.1.

Comment: Just like I wrote, keep in mind that when you'll add custom translations for different languages (not only polish ones) populating schema won't help and you will still need to manually update managed-schema file. By the default Sitecore has hardcoded list of dynamic fields which will be created. This logic is not scanning item versions.

Comment: Ok, that's an information I can work with. Is it possible that you have to restart solr in order to make schema changes work? The rebuild of the index ignored my changes until I restartet the solr service.

Comment: If this answer solved the problem then please accept this answer.

Comment: Is your problem solved? I have tried the same for Bengali & Tamil, but didn't work out.