# copyField dest :'description_t_ta_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField

Tags: solr, indexing

I have added Bengali & Tamil in Sitecore 9.2. In publishing the data I am not getting any issue. But while running the indexing, getting the below error for the fields of the item.

```
copyField dest :'description_t_ta_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.
copyField dest :'description_t_bn_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.
```

In the Managed Schema file in SOLR for both the indexes (web & master) added the below lines based on the solution provided here [Rebuilding Indexes with SOLR throws Exceptions](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/rebuilding-indexes-with-solr-throws-exceptions).

```
<dynamicField name="*_t_ta" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_t_bn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

But the result is the same. Kindly need your expertise for the same.

Comment: Have you also tried the solution described here https://vinayakchauhandotcom.wordpress.com/2019/06/27/sitecore-rebuild-index-issue/?

Comment: It is already in place.   <uniqueKey>_uniqueid</uniqueKey>

Comment: And also after restarting the CM server, the file is got overwritten

Comment: you've added `*_t_ta` to the schema, but your field has `*_t_ta_str` postfix - with `_str`, not sure why your sitecore adds it. Please check `<fieldMap>` config section for such postfix. It contains rules for generating field names, like `{0}_s` for strings and `{0}_t` for indexed text.

Comment: and I would recommend you to extend `<contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>` pipeline instead of editing solr schema files.

Comment: In this pipeline, 9.3 we have an option to createfield.. but in 9.2 I have already tried..  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/add-custom-fields-to-a-solr-schema.html